# make ViewPager.setVisibility(GONE) trigger onPause to onDestroyView callbacks

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'd like to show and hide ViewPager on particular occassions, however this ViewPager element holds quite a bit of Bitmaps that should be recycled. When I do setVisibility(GONE) on VierPager it doesn't trigger any of the callbacks related to its' pages.

Is there any system way to tell ViewPager to destroy view of all the pages it hosts ? I think I could wright somewhat like:

```
foreach(page from viewPagerPages) {
    page.onPause();
    page.onStop();
    page.onDestroyView();
}
```

but I'm not sure about it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To destroy `Views` use `ViewPager's` method [removeAllViews ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeAllViews%28%29). It is inherited from `ViewGroup`.

`removeAllViews () - Call this method to remove all child views from the ViewGroup.`

Here a lot of different methods to manipulate ViewPager.

Comment: uhm, maybe - but how do you feel about what I've supposed - any ramifications involved ? My purpose is not just to remove views but also to recycle bitmaps so I probably would need to do .recycle() on bitmaps of a Hash or ArrayList.

Comment: is you app crashes? OutOfMemory exception? In that case you should call recycle() after your remove view from the pager.

Comment: I'm at the stage of refactoring, it's not crashing yet. But my question was about whether it's safe to call those methods while they're usually called by the system. There might be something else that system might do to a fragment before invoking onPause and the following methods.